# error : Cannot set property 'id' of undefined at UserComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error, undefined

I got the following error: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined at UserComponent.push../src/app/users/user/user.component.ts.UserComponent

TS Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-user",
  templateUrl: "./user.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./user.component.css"],
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: { id: number; name: string };

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<p>User with ID {{user.id}} loaded.</p>
<p>User name is {{user.name}}</p>
```

Comment: Please provide the route Url

Comment: try to use elvis operator on before thje user?.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not initialized your `user` component property that is the reason of the error. So in your scenario, the `user` value is undefined.

You can use the [safe navigation operation](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator) in template to fix this. It will render your UI without giving any errors even when your value is `undefined` or `null`.

```
<p>User with ID {{user?.id}} loaded.</p>
<p>User name is {{user?.name}}</p>
```

The other way would be initializing the values with default value.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
 // Assign the values with default values of corresponding(string in this case) types.
  user: { id: number, name: string } = {id: '', name: ''};

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create user object but as undefined. So you have two solution.

First way is that in costructor initialize user

```
constructor(){
   this.user={id:null,name:null};  
}
```

Second way is that in html make self assign  `{{user?.id}}`